# Hide number in ordered list if there is only one element in the list

Tags: html, css

Say I have a ordered list like this.

```
<ol>
  <li>a</li>
<ol>
```

Since this ol only has one item, I want to render it as

```
a
```

On the other hand, if there are more than one item in the list like below, I want to render 1., 2.s.

```
<ol>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
<ol>
```

should be

```
1. a
2. b
```

Is there a way to do this in pure CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
li:only-of-type { list-style-type: none; }
```

```html
<h1>List 1</h1>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ol>


<h1>List 2</h1>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Wow thanks. this is great